# VBA HTML Coding , Trying To copy Table

Tags: html, vba

I'm trying to pull Table Data from a website after VBA has already opened and clicked Run on the website. But now having trouble trying to copy all the data over to a sheet. I've tried several different codes to try this posted below. Any help would be great.

Here is the code that I have so far .

```
 Sub AHT()



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


sURL = "http://cctools/reporting/main.php?p=centeraht"

' Instructes the macro to open IE and navigate to sURL.
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
     Set HTMLDOC = .Document
End With



Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")





For Each Btninput In appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
    If Btninput.Value = "Run" Then
        Btninput.Click
        Exit For
    End If

 Next



 End Sub
```

I have Tried difference Variations of

```
Set TDelements = appIE.Docuemnt.getElementsByTagName("TD").innerText

        Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents

        r = 0
        For Each TDelement In TDelements
             'Look for required TD elements - this check is specific to VBA Express forum - modify as required
            If TDelement.className = "<>" Then
                Sheet13.Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TDelement.innerText
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Next
```

And this :

```
Sub Extract_TD_text()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDOC As HTMLDocument
    Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
    Dim r As Long

     'Saved from www vbaexpress com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=17
    URL = "http://cctools/reporting/main.php?p=centeraht"

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Navigate URL
        .Visible = True

         'Wait for page to load
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

            Set HTMLDOC = .Document
        End With

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")





For Each Btninput In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
    If Btninput.Value = "Run" Then
        Btninput.Click
        Exit For
    End If

 Next



        Set TDelements = appIE.Docuemnt.getElementsByTagName("TD").innerText

        Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents

        r = 0
        For Each TDelement In TDelements
             'Look for required TD elements - this check is specific to VBA Express forum - modify as required
            If TDelement.className = "data xsmall" Then
                Sheet13.Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TDelement.innerText
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Next
```

But All with no luck. Here is the Source Code of the website after the vba code has already clicked RUn and Generated the Table

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Reporting</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/inc/framework_style.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/inc/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/inc/ajax.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/inc/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/inc/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="menu"><span class='menuheader'>Menu</span>:<br />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='main.php?p=main'>Home</a><br />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='main.php?p=lobscorecard'>LOB Scorecard</a><br />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='main.php?p=vdn'>VDN Report</a><br />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='main.php?p=centeraht'>UV T1 Center AHT Interval</a><br />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='main.php?p=centerahtd'>UV T1 Center AHT Daily</a><br />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='main.php?p=centert2aht'>UV T2 Center AHT Interval</a><br />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='main.php?p=centerT2ahtd'>UV T2 Center AHT Daily</a><br />
    <br />
    </div>
        <div id='fakeheader'></div>
        <div id="main">     <script type='text/javascript'>
            //<![CDATA[
            document.title = 'Reporting - U-Verse T1 AHT Interval - Center Split';
            $(document).ready(function(){
                document.getElementById('subpagetitle').innerHTML='U-Verse T1 AHT Interval - Center Split';
            });
            //]]>
            </script>
    <form method='post' action=''><table class='data'><tr><th>Date</th><th>SubLOB</th><th class='t_custom' title='Comma separated list of agent skills' style='cursor:help; display: none;'>Skills</th></tr><tr><td><input type='text' size='8' id='date' name='date' value='2014-07-13' /></td><td><select name='sublob' onchange="if (this.value == 4) { $('.t_custom').show(); } else { $('.t_custom').hide(); }"><option value=''>All</option><option value='1'>IPDSLAM/CSI</option><option value='2'>Non IPDSLAM/CSI</option><option value='3'>New Blue</option><option value='4'>Custom</option></select></td><td class='t_custom' style='display: none;'><input type='text' name='skills' value='' /></td></tr><tr><th class='center' colspan='3'><input type='submit' value='Run' /></th></tr></table></form>       <script type='text/javascript'>
            //<![CDATA[
    $('#date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',minDate:'2010-05-26',maxDate:'2014-07-13',showOn:'button',buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/img/icon_pickdate.gif'});
            //]]>
            </script>
    Running for 2014-07-12 22:00:00 to 2014-07-13 15:32:49<br/>
Skills Used: 330,325,334,329,331,332,327,328,336,323,361,351,352,353,354,355,357,358,359,356,348,371,375,368,379,347,385,337,338,339,341,343,344,177,176<br/>

<table class='data xsmall'>
<tr><th rowspan='2'>Int</th>
    <th colspan='3' class='center'>ACD Calls</th>
    <th colspan='3' class='center'>Avg ACD</th>
    <th colspan='3' class='center'>Avg ACW</th>
    <th colspan='3' class='center'>Avg Hold</th>
    <th colspan='3' class='center'>AIHT</th>
    <th colspan='3' class='center'>AOHT</th><th rowspan='2' class='center'>Forecast<br/>AHT</th><th colspan='3' class='center'>AIHT+AOHT</th></tr>
<tr><th>SAT</th><th>PHX</th><th>Combined</th><th>SAT</th><th>PHX</th><th>Combined</th>
<th>SAT</th><th>PHX</th><th>Combined</th><th>SAT</th><th>PHX</th><th>Combined</th>
<th>SAT</th><th>PHX</th><th>Combined</th><th>SAT</th><th>PHX</th><th>Combined</th>
<th>SAT</th><th>PHX</th><th>Combined</th></tr><tr><td>0000</td><td>5</td><td>13</td>
<td>18</td><td>7.993</td><td>5.533</td><td>6.217</td><td>1.013</td><td>0.536</td>
<td>0.669</td><td>1.360</td><td>0.460</td><td>0.710</td><td>10.367</td><td>6.529</td>
<td>7.595</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.117</td><td>0.084</td><td>0.000</td><td>10.367</td>
<td>6.646</td><td>7.680</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>0530</td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
<td>0</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td>
<td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td>
<td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td>
<td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td></tr><tr><td>0600</td><td>11</td><td>0</td><td>11</td>
<td>22.050</td><td>0.000</td><td>22.050</td><td>2.126</td><td>0.000</td><td>2.126</td>
<td>0.956</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.956</td><td>25.132</td><td>0.000</td><td>25.132</td>
<td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>0.000</td><td>13.825</td><td>25.132</td><td>0.000</td>
<td>25.132</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>0630</td><td>20</td><td>0</td><td>20</td>
<td>21.952</td><td>0.000</td><td>23.863</td><td>3.380</td><td>0.000</td><td>3.380</td>
<td>2.262</td><td>0.000</td><td>2.354</td><td>27.593</td><td>0.000</td><td>29.597</td><td>1.576</td><td>0.000</td><td>1.576</td><td>14.839</td><td>29.169</td><td>0.000</td><td>31.172</td></tr><tr><td>0700</td><td>42</td><td>12</td><td>54</td><td>17.212</td><td>7.740</td><td>15.107</td><td>1.444</td><td>0.368</td><td>1.205</td><td>2.442</td><td>0.826</td><td>2.083</td><td>21.099</td><td>8.935</td><td>18.396</td><td>0.561</td><td>0.171</td><td>0.474</td><td>15.983</td><td>21.660</td><td>9.106</td><td>18.870</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>0730</td><td>73</td><td>9</td><td>82</td><td>13.539</td><td>15.046</td><td>13.705</td><td>1.005</td><td>1.272</td><td>1.035</td><td>2.057</td><td>1.059</td><td>1.947</td><td>16.602</td><td>17.378</td><td>16.687</td><td>0.142</td><td>0.681</td><td>0.201</td><td>15.867</td><td>16.743</td><td>18.059</td><td>16.888</td></tr><tr><td>0800</td><td>86</td><td>20</td><td>106</td><td>12.600</td><td>15.325</td><td>13.114</td><td>1.924</td><td>0.767</td><td>1.705</td><td>1.237</td><td>1.394</td><td>1.267</td><td>15.761</td><td>17.486</td><td>16.086</td><td>0.715</td><td>0.014</td><td>0.582</td><td>15.250</td><td>16.475</td><td>17.500</td><td>16.669</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>0830</td><td>70</td><td>19</td><td>89</td><td>13.039</td><td>20.487</td><td>14.629</td><td>1.552</td><td>1.546</td><td>1.551</td><td>1.995</td><td>5.735</td><td>2.793</td><td>16.586</td><td>27.768</td><td>18.973</td><td>1.098</td><td>0.107</td><td>0.887</td><td>17.333</td><td>17.685</td><td>27.875</td><td>19.860</td></tr><tr><td>0900</td><td>79</td><td>33</td><td>112</td><td>11.347</td><td>17.452</td><td>13.146</td><td>1.410</td><td>1.835</td><td>1.536</td><td>1.438</td><td>5.544</td><td>2.648</td><td>14.195</td><td>24.831</td><td>17.329</td><td>0.624</td><td>1.274</td><td>0.815</td><td>17.065</td><td>14.819</td><td>26.105</td><td>18.144</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>0930</td><td>62</td><td>58</td><td>120</td><td>11.863</td><td>9.514</td><td>10.728</td><td>1.278</td><td>1.530</td><td>1.400</td><td>1.868</td><td>2.609</td><td>2.226</td><td>15.009</td><td>13.654</td><td>14.354</td><td>0.705</td><td>0.721</td><td>0.713</td><td>16.625</td><td>15.714</td><td>14.375</td><td>15.067</td></tr><tr><td>1000</td><td>73</td><td>39</td><td>112</td><td>12.805</td><td>13.308</td><td>12.980</td><td>1.366</td><td>1.086</td><td>1.269</td><td>1.723</td><td>2.753</td><td>2.081</td><td>15.893</td><td>17.147</td><td>16.330</td><td>0.360</td><td>0.753</td><td>0.497</td><td>17.275</td><td>16.253</td><td>17.900</td><td>16.827</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>1030</td><td>106</td><td>30</td><td>136</td><td>10.530</td><td>15.892</td><td>11.713</td><td>2.047</td><td>1.909</td><td>2.016</td><td>1.658</td><td>3.136</td><td>1.984</td><td>14.234</td><td>20.937</td><td>15.712</td><td>0.341</td><td>1.141</td><td>0.517</td><td>17.139</td><td>14.574</td><td>22.078</td><td>16.230</td></tr><tr><td>1100</td><td>98</td><td>44</td><td>142</td><td>9.911</td><td>14.486</td><td>11.329</td><td>1.027</td><td>0.799</td><td>0.956</td><td>0.888</td><td>2.059</td><td>1.251</td><td>11.825</td><td>17.344</td><td>13.535</td><td>0.630</td><td>0.203</td><td>0.498</td><td>16.017</td><td>12.455</td><td>17.547</td><td>14.033</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>1130</td><td>93</td><td>60</td><td>153</td><td>10.327</td><td>12.664</td><td>11.243</td><td>1.621</td><td>1.053</td><td>1.398</td><td>1.052</td><td>1.229</td><td>1.122</td><td>13.000</td><td>14.946</td><td>13.763</td><td>0.369</td><td>0.268</td><td>0.329</td><td>16.751</td><td>13.369</td><td>15.214</td><td>14.092</td></tr><tr><td>1200</td><td>107</td><td>61</td><td>168</td><td>11.503</td><td>13.919</td><td>12.380</td><td>1.101</td><td>0.948</td><td>1.046</td><td>1.538</td><td>1.524</td><td>1.533</td><td>14.143</td><td>16.391</td><td>14.959</td><td>0.851</td><td>0.526</td><td>0.733</td><td>15.800</td><td>14.994</td><td>16.917</td><td>15.692</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>1230</td><td>127</td><td>60</td><td>187</td><td>9.198</td><td>12.893</td><td>10.384</td><td>1.638</td><td>0.870</td><td>1.392</td><td>0.814</td><td>0.971</td><td>0.864</td><td>11.650</td><td>14.734</td><td>12.639</td><td>0.690</td><td>0.506</td><td>0.631</td><td>16.217</td><td>12.340</td><td>15.240</td><td>13.270</td></tr><tr><td>1300</td><td>105</td><td>50</td><td>155</td><td>11.266</td><td>13.160</td><td>11.877</td><td>1.067</td><td>0.825</td><td>0.989</td><td>0.603</td><td>0.668</td><td>0.624</td><td>12.936</td><td>14.653</td><td>13.490</td><td>0.917</td><td>1.330</td><td>1.050</td><td>16.271</td><td>13.853</td><td>15.983</td><td>14.540</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>1330</td><td>105</td><td>59</td><td>164</td><td>11.154</td><td>13.355</td><td>11.946</td><td>1.243</td><td>0.844</td><td>1.100</td><td>0.620</td><td>1.049</td><td>0.774</td><td>13.017</td><td>15.248</td><td>13.819</td><td>1.130</td><td>0.923</td><td>1.055</td><td>16.908</td><td>14.147</td><td>16.171</td><td>14.875</td></tr><tr><td>1400</td><td>95</td><td>50</td><td>145</td><td>15.041</td><td>19.103</td><td>16.441</td><td>1.443</td><td>1.386</td><td>1.423</td><td>1.683</td><td>1.796</td><td>1.722</td><td>18.166</td><td>22.285</td><td>19.586</td><td>0.926</td><td>0.472</td><td>0.770</td><td>17.075</td><td>19.093</td><td>22.757</td><td>20.356</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>1430</td><td>99</td><td>70</td><td>169</td><td>13.438</td><td>14.066</td><td>13.698</td><td>1.331</td><td>0.935</td><td>1.167</td><td>1.942</td><td>1.553</td><td>1.781</td><td>16.711</td><td>16.553</td><td>16.646</td><td>0.948</td><td>1.363</td><td>1.120</td><td>17.000</td><td>17.659</td><td>17.916</td><td>17.765</td></tr><tr><td>1500</td><td>84</td><td>78</td><td>162</td><td>14.921</td><td>13.699</td><td>14.333</td><td>1.390</td><td>1.162</td><td>1.280</td><td>1.872</td><td>1.295</td><td>1.594</td><td>18.183</td><td>16.156</td><td>17.207</td><td>1.286</td><td>0.859</td><td>1.080</td><td>17.575</td><td>19.469</td><td>17.015</td><td>18.287</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>1530</td><td>67</td><td>63</td><td>130</td><td>18.298</td><td>14.476</td><td>16.446</td><td>1.833</td><td>0.850</td><td>1.357</td><td>1.863</td><td>0.979</td><td>1.435</td><td>21.995</td><td>16.306</td><td>19.238</td><td>1.398</td><td>1.207</td><td>1.305</td><td>16.475</td><td>23.392</td><td>17.513</td><td>20.543</td></tr><tr><td>1600</td><td>74</td><td>61</td><td>135</td><td>17.055</td><td>18.697</td><td>17.797</td><td>2.100</td><td>1.473</td><td>1.817</td><td>1.655</td><td>2.616</td><td>2.089</td><td>20.810</td><td>22.786</td><td>21.703</td><td>0.823</td><td>0.807</td><td>0.816</td><td>16.850</td><td>21.634</td><td>23.593</td><td>22.519</td></tr><tr class='altrow'><td>1630</td><td>67</td><td>71</td><td>138</td><td>17.288</td><td>13.447</td><td>15.312</td><td>2.450</td><td>1.115</td><td>1.763</td><td>2.284</td><td>1.648</td><td>1.957</td><td>22.022</td><td>16.211</td><td>19.032</td><td>1.534</td><td>1.423</td><td>1.477</td><td>16.181</td><td>23.556</td><td>17.634</td><td>20.509</td></tr><tr><td>Total</td>
<td>1748</td><td>960</td><td>2708</td><td>12.846</td><td>14.207</td><td>13.329</td>
<td>1.521</td><td>1.108</td><td>1.375</td><td>1.478</td><td>1.821</td><td>1.600</td>
<td>15.846</td><td>17.137</td><td>16.303</td><td>0.799</td><td>0.813</td><td>0.804</td>
<td>16.622</td><td>16.644</td><td>17.950</td><td>17.107</td></tr>
</table><br/>

<a href='csvexport.php'>CSV Export</a><br/></div>
        <div id="fakefooter"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><p><span class='copyright'>&copy;  2014</span></p></div>
    <div id="header"><div class='left'><img src='/img/pace_logo_smaller.gif' alt='Pace Logo' /></div><div class='right'><div style='float: right;'>User:  [<a href='index.php?logout=1'>Logout</a>]<br />Access Level: User<br /></div></div><span class='subtitle' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick="document.location='main.php';">Reporting</span><br/><span id='subpagetitle'></span></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: hmmm table appears to be dynamically served from javascript function so it may not be directly accessible from the IE object. Should be possible to copy the webpage entirely (google it or search SO for how-to's) and parse that as a worst-case-scenario.

Comment: Both the samples you post have the exact same typo:  `Set TDelements = appIE.Docuemnt.getElementsByTagName("TD").innerText`  Note `Docuemnt` is mis-spelled.  Try fixing that, then if you still have problems update your question with the *exact* error you get, or if you get no error then *exactly what happens*.  "All with no luck" doesn't really give us much to go on.

Comment: Apologies. I've gotten the codes to run and no errors occur. I've adjusted the classnames for any class=" " in the code i find. But nothing ever gets pasted into the sheet.

Comment: @DavidZemens ,Im gonna attempt to do the copy and paste whole paste thing. With.                                                .IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_SELECTALL, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_COPY, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
ActiveSheet.Paste.                                                type code. But only problem is when I adapt this for a few other things Im doing copying the whole webpage will add way to many un needed info and hyperlinks and such.

Comment: Tim i fixed the spelling but still get no luck when trying to pull data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100894/pull-html-table-data-into-excel-sheet

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the oode to work using the copy and paste it all. And use two more subs to clear out extra items not needed .

```
Global slogininfo As String
    Global appIE As Object ' InternetExplorer.Application
    Global sURL As String
    Global sLogin As String
    Global sNotes As String
    Global ID As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Global infraction As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Global Element As Object ' HTMLButtonElement
    Global Btninput As Object ' MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Global ElementCol As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Sub AHT()



    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


    sURL = "http://cctools/reporting/main.php?p=centeraht"

    ' Instructes the macro to open IE and navigate to sURL.
    With appIE
        .Navigate sURL
        .Visible = True

        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
         Set HTMLDOC = .Document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

    For Each Btninput In appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
        If Btninput.Value = "Run" Then
            Btninput.Click
            Exit For
        End If

     Next

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")


           appIE.ExecWB OLECMDID_SELECTALL, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
        appIE.ExecWB OLECMDID_COPY, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT




    appIE.Quit

    Range("A1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste


    Call Cleanup
    Call DeleteObj



     End Sub







     Sub Cleanup()
    '
    ' Cleanup Macro
    '

    '
        Rows("1:15").Select
        Range("A15").Activate
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-24
    End Sub



    Sub DeleteObj()
    Dim obj As Object
    For Each obj In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    obj.Delete
    Next
    End Sub
```

Now with another site I had issues with the copy and paste method wasn't working. But the site has a CSV option to download the date i altered the code to capture that and paste it as such.

```
Sub Metrics()



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


sURL = "http://cctools/rportal/main.php?p=agentavaya"

' Instructes the macro to open IE and navigate to sURL.
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
     Set HTMLDOC = .Document
End With



Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")


For Each Btninput In appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
    If Btninput.Value = " Run " Then
        Btninput.Click
        Exit For
    End If

 Next


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")

Call CSV






 End Sub




Sub CSV()
sCSVLink = "http://cctools/rportal/csvexport.php"
sfile = "csvexport.php"
ssheet = "Sheet10"

Set wnd = ActiveWindow

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Workbooks.Open Filename:=sCSVLink

Windows(sfile).Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
wnd.Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Windows(sfile).Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```